# What are the algorithms supported by JsafeJCE for KeyManagerFactory?

Tags: java, ssl, rsa, jce

In our project we need to communicate with a third party server on SSL.
Earlier we were using sslJ provider `com.rsa.jsse.JsseProvider` from RSA, but because of some issue in it, now we have to use Sun's SSL provider `com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider` and we need to use crypto provider "JsafeJCE" of RSA for FIPS compliance.

I am facing problem while creating KeyManagerFactory using JsafeJCE provider.

```
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("PKCS12",
    "JsafeJCE");
```

Following is the exception I get

> Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: PKCS12 for provider JsafeJCE

Can someone please tell me the algorithms supported by JsafeJCE for KeyManagerFactory?

Comment: Looking at [this page](https://developer-content.emc.com/docs/rsashare/share_for_java/1.1/jce/com/rsa/jsafe/provider/JsafeJCE.html) it seems it offers no `KeyManager` implementations.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've installed the RSA JsseProvider and JsafeJCE correctly.

`PKCS12` is a `KeyStore` type, not a `KeyManager` type. It doesn't make sense to create a `KeyManagerFactory` of type `PKCS12`, perhaps you meant `KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "JsafeJCE")`.

Otherwise, if you were after a `KeyManagerFactory`, it is a JSSE class, not a JCE class, so it would expect a JSSE provider, not a JCE provider. The [provider name for the RSA JsseProvider](https://developer-content.emc.com/docs/rsashare/share_for_java/1.1/jsse/com/rsa/jsse/JsseProvider.html#NAME) is "`RsaJsse`", not "`JsafeJCE`" (although it will use that JCE provider behind the scenes, see [this note](https://developer-content.emc.com/docs/rsashare/share_for_java/1.1/dev_guide/group__LEARNJSSE__OVERVIEW__PROVIDER__DYN.html)).

> Can someone please tell me the algorithms supported by JsafeJCE for KeyManagerFactory?

According to the [documentation](https://developer-content.emc.com/docs/rsashare/share_for_java/1.1/jsse/com/rsa/jsse/JsseProvider.html) the supported KMF name should be ["`X509`"](https://developer-content.emc.com/docs/rsashare/share_for_java/1.1/jsse/constant-values.html#com.rsa.jsse.JsseProvider.X509), although some aliases are also valid.